# Concatenate commands through __add__

Tags: python, class, concatenation

I have a class called "Car", which simulates the movements of a car through the command *forward* and changes direction thanks to some other ones, that I already wrote (default direction: right).

```
E.g. [if starting from (0,0) (top left)]: 
c = Car()
c.forward(8).right(3)  increases the value of the "x" at first: (8, 0) an then changes direction to left (= from "right" the direction becomes "down") and exectues a forward of 3 (= the value of the "y" increased by 3 (8, 3).
```

What I need to do is modify the special method "**add**", inside the same class, to concatenate two commands, in order to make the second one start where the first one stops and return a new "Car" object (which contains the concatenation).

E.g.:

```
  c1 = Car().right(3).left(3)
  c2 = Car().left(3).right(3)
  c = c1 + c2

Should (starting from (2,2)): 
1.0)Change direction to right, execute a forward by "3" -> (2,5)
1.1)Change the direction to left, execute a forward by "3" -> (5,5)
From where the c1 object stopped:
2.0)Change direction to left, execute the forward -> (5,2)
2.1)Change direction to right, execute the last forward (8,2)
```

How could I do something like that?

Comment: Does a `Car` represent a *car*, or a *sequence of commands to a car*? In particular, does `c.forward(8).right(3)` actually *perform* the commands, or does it just build a sequence? Either this class is badly named and it should be something like `DriveCommands`, or adding two `Car`s doesn't make sense.

Comment: The fact that you can chain the methods strongly implies each returns a `Car` instance. `__add__` should probably just do pairwise addition, i.e., (x, y) + (a, b) = (x+a, y+b).

Comment: The __init__ contains the starting point (x, y) and sets the default direction to "right", then the forward attribute increases/decreases (depending on the direction) the value of the x and y. Ofc forward returns the same object in order to make more than one movement. So maybe you're right, it builds a sequence